# Google Charts Timeline highlight many bars on mouseover

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm currently working on some data visualization. For the visualization I am using Google Charts Timeline embedded within Dashboard (which implements functionality of zooming on x-axis). Timeline is representing players position in ranking (first, second and third place). What I am trying to achieve is - when i hover mouse on player's entry I would like to highlight his/hers other entries in timeline. Using Google's example with President, VP and Secretary of State - when I hover over Thomas Jefferson bar when he was Secretary of State I want his time as VP and as President highlighted on the chart. I am providing jsfiddle as a reference - https://jsfiddle.net/21aor2ab/

I had an idea about using 'onmouseover' event, but I had problem with setting this event properly within dashboard - simply using
`google.visualization.events.addListener(dashChart, 'onmouseover', function(){something over here});` won't work for some reason...

I would be happy if anyone could suggest me a solution, or at least point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when assigning *chart* events to *chart wrappers*...

you have to wait for the `'ready'` event on the wrapper,
then listen for the event on `wrapper.getChart()`

see following example...

as for highlighting multiple entries,
here I try to `trigger` the `onmouseover` on the other rows,
the event is fired but the rows aren't highlighted

I thought about using `setSelection` instead, but for a Timeline chart...

*only one entity can be selected at any given moment*

only other option would be to modify the svg directly
but not recommended
you would need to log all the colors, including the highlight colors,
or try to provide your own

this example highlights all the Thomas Jefferson rows

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

    var dashControl = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
      'containerId': 'control',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnIndex': 3,
        'ui': {
          'chartType': 'ScatterChart',
          'chartOptions': {
            'height': 70,
            'chartArea': {
              width: '80%',
              height: '80%'
            },
            'hAxis': {
              'baselineColor': 'none'
            }
          },
          'chartView': {
            'columns': [3, 4]
          },
          minRangeSize: 12*60*60*1000
        }
      }
    });

    var dashChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'Timeline',
      'containerId': 'chart',
      'options': {
        'chartArea': {
          width: '80%',
          height: '80%'
        },
        hAxis: {
          format: 'dd.MM HH:mm'
        }
      },
      'view': {
        'columns': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
      }
    });

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Role' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: "string", id: "", "role": "tooltip", "p" : { "role" : "tooltip" ,'html': true} });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

    dataTable.addRows([
      [ 'President', 'George Washington', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'President', 'John Adams', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'President', 'Thomas Jefferson', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'Vice President', 'John Adams', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1789, 3, 21), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
      [ 'Vice President', 'Thomas Jefferson', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
      [ 'Vice President', 'Aaron Burr', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1805, 2, 4)],
      [ 'Vice President', 'George Clinton', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1805, 2, 4), new Date(1812, 3, 20)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'John Jay', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1789, 8, 25), new Date(1790, 2, 22)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'Thomas Jefferson', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1790, 2, 22), new Date(1793, 11, 31)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'Edmund Randolph', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1794, 0, 2), new Date(1795, 7, 20)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'Timothy Pickering', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1795, 7, 20), new Date(1800, 4, 12)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'Charles Lee', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1800, 4, 13), new Date(1800, 5, 5)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'John Marshall', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1800, 5, 13), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'Levi Lincoln', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1801, 2, 5), new Date(1801, 4, 1)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'James Madison', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1801, 4, 2), new Date(1809, 2, 3)]
    ]);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(dashChart, 'ready', function () {
      google.visualization.events.addListener(dashChart.getChart(), 'onmouseover', function (e) {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementById(dashChart.getContainerId()).getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(bar) {
          if (bar.getAttribute('fill') === '#f4b400') {
            bar.setAttribute('fill', '#f7cb4d')
          }
        });
      });
      google.visualization.events.addListener(dashChart.getChart(), 'onmouseout', function (e) {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementById(dashChart.getContainerId()).getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(bar) {
          if (bar.getAttribute('fill') === '#f7cb4d') {
            bar.setAttribute('fill', '#f4b400')
          }
        });
      });
    });

    dashboard.bind(dashControl, dashChart);
    dashboard.draw(dataTable);
  },
  packages:['controls', 'corechart', 'timeline']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
    <div id="chart" style="height: 200px;"></div>
    <div id="control"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! that definitely is a step forward - now I just have to find some way to highlight all entries for given row. I was thinking about using some sort of color-based selector (since each person gets unique color), but it won't be that easy, because when you hover mouse over bar - the color changes to highlight given bar... still - it's a step forward!

Comment: you could try modifying the svg directly -- but not recommended, and as you stated, not easy...

Comment: yes, that was what I was thinking - editing svg directly. i know, that specifying custom colors would make it easier, but since in extreme case the chart can possibly contain about 500 people it is not going to be an easy one. thanks anyway - if I come up with solution I will let you know!

Comment: i am happy to accept your answer as it pointed me in the right direction - I was able to tweak it a bit, and achieve my goal with a little bit of jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

with a little bit of tweaking using jQuery I was able to achieve my goal. just posting this for future reference or possible google'rs

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

    var dashControl = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
      'containerId': 'control',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnIndex': 3,
        'ui': {
          'chartType': 'ScatterChart',
          'chartOptions': {
            'height': 70,
            'chartArea': {
              width: '80%',
              height: '80%'
            },
            'hAxis': {
              'baselineColor': 'none'
            }
          },
          'chartView': {
            'columns': [3, 4]
          },
          minRangeSize: 12*60*60*1000
        }
      }
    });

    var dashChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'Timeline',
      'containerId': 'chart',
      'options': {
        'chartArea': {
          width: '80%',
          height: '80%'
        },
        hAxis: {
          format: 'dd.MM HH:mm'
        }
      },
      'view': {
        'columns': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
      }
    });

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Role' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: "string", id: "", "role": "tooltip", "p" : { "role" : "tooltip" ,'html': true} });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

    dataTable.addRows([
      [ 'President', 'George Washington', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'President', 'John Adams', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'President', 'Thomas Jefferson', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'Vice President', 'John Adams', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1789, 3, 21), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
      [ 'Vice President', 'Thomas Jefferson', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
      [ 'Vice President', 'Aaron Burr', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1805, 2, 4)],
      [ 'Vice President', 'George Clinton', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1805, 2, 4), new Date(1812, 3, 20)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'John Jay', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1789, 8, 25), new Date(1790, 2, 22)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'Thomas Jefferson', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1790, 2, 22), new Date(1793, 11, 31)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'Edmund Randolph', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1794, 0, 2), new Date(1795, 7, 20)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'Timothy Pickering', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1795, 7, 20), new Date(1800, 4, 12)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'Charles Lee', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1800, 4, 13), new Date(1800, 5, 5)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'John Marshall', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1800, 5, 13), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'Levi Lincoln', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1801, 2, 5), new Date(1801, 4, 1)],
      [ 'Secretary of State', 'James Madison', 'some tooltip content', new Date(1801, 4, 2), new Date(1809, 2, 3)]
    ]);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(dashChart, 'ready', function () {
  var original_rect_color;
  var new_rect_color;
  google.visualization.events.addListener(dashChart.getChart(), 'onmouseover', function (e) {
    var original_rect = $("div#dashboard div#chart g rect").filter(function(){return $(this).attr('style') == 'display: none;'})[0];
 var temp_original_color = $(original_rect).attr('fill');
 if(temp_original_color!=original_rect_color)
 {
  $("div#dashboard div#chart g rect").filter(function(){return $(this).attr('fill') == new_rect_color}).each(function(){
   $(this).attr('fill',original_rect_color);
  });
 }
 original_rect_color = temp_original_color;
 var original_rect_x = $(original_rect).attr('x');
 var original_rect_y = $(original_rect).attr('y');
 new_rect_color = $($("div#dashboard div#chart g rect").filter(function(){return $(this).attr('x') == original_rect_x && $(this).attr('y') == original_rect_y})[1]).attr('fill');
 $("div#dashboard div#chart g rect").filter(function(){return $(this).attr('fill') == original_rect_color}).each(function(){
  $(this).attr('fill',new_rect_color);
 });
  });
  google.visualization.events.addListener(dashChart.getChart(), 'onmouseout', function (e) {
    $("div#dashboard div#chart g rect").filter(function(){return $(this).attr('fill') == new_rect_color}).each(function(){
  $(this).attr('fill',original_rect_color);
 });
  });
});

    dashboard.bind(dashControl, dashChart);
    dashboard.draw(dataTable);
  },
  packages:['controls', 'corechart', 'timeline']
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
    <div id="chart" style="height: 200px;"></div>
    <div id="control"></div>
</div>
```