# Unable to show tooltips in Gantt Chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I was trying to meddle in the JSFiddle given as an example for Gantt Chart to show more information on hovering over the colored bar in a Gantt chart. Here is the [Link for fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpxk5dej/2/). I am using [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

I've added the

```
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
  data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'},"Extra Info");
```

and the data row is

```
['Outline', 'Outline paper',
     null, new Date(2015, 0, 6), daysToMilliseconds(1), 100, 'Research',"GG"]
```

where GG is the extra information

How do I make sure that the extra information is displayed on hovering over the bar?

Comment: unfortunately, the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#data-format) for a gantt chart does not allow for tooltip columns -- nor does it publish an event for `'onmouseover'` -- very limited on customization

Comment: @WhiteHat do you know any alternative javascript packages which can be used to achieve this and has the existing functionalities of Google charts gantt charts?

Comment: sorry, only familiar with google charts -- the timeline chart would be the closest alternative there...

Comment: @WhiteHat can we change different colors of bars with same row label in Timeline?

Comment: don't follow exactly, run the snippet added to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37658395/5090771) -- when you say, _same row label_, the timeline will add all data table rows, with the same _row label_, to the same bar, such as "President" in the snippet i reference. the `colors` option, in timeline chart, follows the second column, _bar label_...